# Adding a label column of string to the data array

Tags: python, numpy

I was wondering how to add a column of text labels such as 'cluster1', 'cluster2' to an array.
Below is my clustered data and code that creates labels of integers 1,2,3.

```
label1 = np.ones((len(cluster1),1))*1
label2 = np.ones((len(cluster2),1))*2
label3 = np.ones((len(cluster3),1))*3

cluster1_labeled = np.hstack((cluster1,label1))
cluster2_labeled = np.hstack((cluster2,label2))
cluster3_labeled = np.hstack((cluster3,label3))

data_labeled = np.vstack((cluster1_labeled,cluster2_labeled,cluster3_labeled))
```

The output I have right now looks like this (120 x 4 array):

```
[-4.84937296  0.41915891  6.64321784  1.        ]
...
[ 2.14329881 -3.44530181  4.40986279  2.        ]
...
[-3.70757636 -5.11940093 -2.53982243  3.        ]
...
```

Comment: Sorry, I figured this out using np.full()